# Issues while updating GMA3600 drivers

Tags: drivers

I own an Acer Aspire One D270. Intel has released its newest driver version for GMA3600 but I am unable to install one on my Windows 7 32 Bit OS.

The installation throws a "not validated for this computer" error. I tried updating via the device manager - have disk option. It fails there too. Any inputs or links to beta drivers would be appreciated. The system runs on Intel N2600 outside with GMA3600 GPU inside.

My current driver version is 1085. The driver that I tried to install (v1091) resides [here](http://communities.intel.com/thread/38490). The Acer website provides no link for the update though.